# How to tell AP flour from self-rising flour?

Tags: flour

I have a tupperware container of all-purpose flour, and another of self-rising flour.  Sadly, I did not label them, and now I've forgotten which is which.

Is there an easy way to tell them apart?

Answer (score 2):

Take a little bit of each and add water.  The self rising flour will look noticably different (bubbling etc) than the normal flour.